# join multiple files

Tags: linux, join, sed

I am using the standard join command to join two sorted files based on column1.
The command is simple join file1 file2 > output_file.

But how do I join 3 or more files using the same technique ?
join file1 file2 file3 > output_file
Above command gave me an empty file.
I think sed can help me but I am not too sure how ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`man join`:

```
NAME
       join - join lines of two files on a common field

SYNOPSIS
       join [OPTION]... FILE1 FILE2
```

it only works with **two** files.

if you need to join three, maybe you can first join the first two, then join the third.

try:

```
join file1 file2 | join - file3 > output
```

that should join the three files without creating an intermediate temp file. `-` tells the join command to read the first input stream from `stdin`

Comment: what do you mean by a hyphen for the second join ?? is it a special symbol for join ??

Comment: see my update. `-` is understood by many unix program as shorthand for stdin/stdout

Answer (score 13):

One can join multiple files (N>=2) by constructing a pipeline of `join`s recursively:

```
#!/bin/sh

# multijoin - join multiple files

join_rec() {
    if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
        join - "$1"
    else
        f=$1; shift
        join - "$f" | join_rec "$@"
    fi
}

if [ $# -le 2 ]; then
    join "$@"
else
    f1=$1; f2=$2; shift 2
    join "$f1" "$f2" | join_rec "$@"
fi
```

Comment: Definitely my favourite answer! However, I replaced the `join_rec` function's body by this : `f1=$1; f2=$2; shift 2; 
    if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then; 
        join "$f1" "$f2" | join_rec - "$@";
    else;
        join "$f1" "$f2";
    fi` as to eliminate the need for the second `if`. The call would look like `join_rec "$@"`

Comment: @ack Is it possible to add file name as header in the output ?

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old question but for future reference.
If you know that the files you want to join have a pattern like in the question here e.g. `file1 file2 file3 ... fileN`
Then you can simply join them with this command

```
cat file* > output
```

Where output will be the series of the joined files which were joined in alphabetical order.

Comment: This works superb for text files. How about the binary files which have been split using other commands / packages / software.

Comment: well there you have probably some header in every file which indicates, what kind of file is it, so there is this not sufficient, but you should search for other so questions for this, i am sure someone solved it already

Comment: The question is to join corresponding rows in the input files together. Not concatenating them.

Answer (score 6):

I created a function for this. First argument is the output file, rest arguments are the files to be joined.

```
function multijoin() {
    out=$1
    shift 1
    cat $1 | awk '{print $1}' > $out
    for f in $*; do join $out $f > tmp; mv tmp $out; done
}
```

Usage:

```
multijoin output_file file*
```

Comment: Thanks, this was useful. if someone wants to add the header then sed -i '1i header_text' output_file

Answer (score 4):

While a bit an old question, this is how you can do it with a single `awk`:

```
awk -v j=<field_number> '{key=$j; $j=""}  # get key and delete field j
                         (NR==FNR){order[FNR]=key;} # store the key-order
                         {entry[key]=entry[key] OFS $0 } # update key-entry
                         END { for(i=1;i<=FNR;++i) {
                                  key=order[i]; print key entry[key] # print
                               }
                         }' file1 ... filen
```

This script assumes:

- all files have the same amount of lines
- the order of the output is the same order of the first file.
- files do not need to be sorted in field `<field_number>`
- `<field_number>` is a valid integer.

Answer (score 3):

The `man` page of `join` states that it only works for two files. So you need to create and intermediate file, which you delete afterwards, i.e.:

```
> join file1 file2 > temp
> join temp file3 > output
> rm temp
```

Comment: Or `join <(join file1 file2) file3`

Comment: @Kevin Sweet! Didn't know that one!

Comment: do you mean `rm temp` ?

Answer (score 0):

Join joins lines of **two files** on a common field. If you want to join more - do it in pairs. Join first two files first, then join the result with a third file etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have four files A.txt, B.txt, C.txt and D.txt as:

```
~$ cat A.txt
x1 2
x2 3
x4 5
x5 8

~$ cat B.txt
x1 5
x2 7
x3 4
x4 6

~$ cat C.txt
x2 1
x3 1
x4 1
x5 1

~$ cat D.txt
x1 1
```

Join the files with:

```
firstOutput='0,1.2'; secondOutput='2.2'; myoutput="$firstOutput,$secondOutput"; outputCount=3; join -a 1 -a 2 -e 0 -o "$myoutput" A.txt B.txt > tmp.tmp; for f in C.txt D.txt; do firstOutput="$firstOutput,1.$outputCount"; myoutput="$firstOutput,$secondOutput"; join -a 1 -a 2 -e 0 -o "$myoutput" tmp.tmp $f > tempf; mv tempf tmp.tmp; outputCount=$(($outputCount+1)); done; mv tmp.tmp files_join.txt
```

Results:

```
~$ cat files_join.txt 
x1 2 5 0 1
x2 3 7 1 0
x3 0 4 1 0
x4 5 6 1 0
x5 8 0 1 0
```