# Merge two HTML files into master HTML file

Tags: html, linux, join, merge

Let's say I have the following HTML files:

**html1.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="blah.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>this here be a div, y'all</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**html2.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="blah.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span>this here be a span, y'all</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to take these two files and make a master file that would look like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="blah.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="blah.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>this here be a div, y'all</div>
    <span>this here be a span, y'all</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is this possible using a simple Linux command?  I've tried looking at [join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726471/join-multiple-files), but it looks like that joins on a common field, and I'm not necessarily going to have common fields... I just need to basically add the difference, but also have the main structure still intact (I guess this could be referred to as a left-join?).  Doesn't look like `cat` will work either... as that merges by appending one file, then the next, etc.

If there isn't a simple Linux command, my next step is to either write a script that compares both scripts line by line, or create a master HTML file that references these two individual files somehow.

Comment: FYI, If you just concatenate the two files together, as is, they will display one after the other in most browsers.  

Or, you can create a 'master' HTML file, that will load each of these files in frames.

Comment: Yep, but that's not an option for what I need done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example files are well-formed XHTML. Excellent! This means you can use a simple XSLT script. See [How to merge two XML files with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194718/how-to-merge-two-xml-files-with-xslt)

Comment: What is this trickery?  I've never heard of XSLT before... interesting.  I shall look into this, and if I can create a working script, I'll accept this answer (unless someone comes along with a nice Linux command).  Thanks.

Comment: This will only work if all your real HTML files are also well-formed XML (i.e. they follow the syntax rules of XML).

Comment: My HTML files (that I'm trying to merge) get generated by another application, but they appear to be well-formed.

Comment: Sometimes it's possible  to "fix" messy HTML with `xmllint`

Comment: Please can you tell me how you did this using XSLT. Can you share the script link or method that you used to solve this problem.

Answer (score 12):

Use [pandoc](http://pandoc.org) to merge e.g. all html-files in the current directory:

```
pandoc -s *.html -o output.html
```

Comment: The html links in a document generated in this way do not work.

Comment: In 2022, links work for me. But it breaks the layout.

Comment: 2024. Links don't work. The layout is broken.

Answer (score 6):

You can use html-merge tool to merge multiple HTML files preserving their internal hypertext links. It's a win32 program, but you can run it in linux using Wine. Download page: https://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlmg/files/

Comment: I had to change all the source file encodings to UTF-8, but after that it worked a charm! Thanks!

Comment: doesn't work when the encoding is Chinese "GB2312" :( There is no source code either, so I couldn't correct it.

Comment: The supported encodings are listed in the README file for the program. They currently include ISO-8859-1/2/3, Windows-1250/1/2/3, UTF-16, UTF-16BE, UTF-8. Some html files do not have encoding specified, and contain characters that do not allow them to be treated as UTF-8 by default.

Comment: Adding support for Asian character sets is not trivial, because the program uses custom HTML parser, and the input files may have different encodings. This means that the fix would require adding your own transcoding routines and tables for GB2312. Also, html-merge always outputs UTF-8, partly because of the same need to choose one universal encoding for differently encoded input. UTF-16 would produce larger files for European languages.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution that uses Python's [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) library, though it will only copy element children of the `body` tag selected `child::*`, not text nodes, which would require a modification `child::node()` and some extra logic for dealing with appending text nodes.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys, os
from lxml.html import tostring, parse

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
  print("Usage: merge.py [file1] ... [filen] [outfile]")

if os.path.isfile(sys.argv[-1]):
   if input('Override? (y/n) ' + sys.argv[-1]) != 'y':
      sys.exit(0)

def tostr(n):
  try:
    return tostring(n)
  except:
    return str(n)

tree = parse(sys.argv[1])
for f in sys.argv[2:-1]:
  print(f)
  tree2 = parse(f)
  for n in tree2.xpath('//head/child::*'):
     if all([tostr(n) != tostr(n2)\
        for n2 in tree2.xpath('//head/child::*')]):
       tree.xpath('//head')[0].append(n)
  for n in tree2.xpath('//body/child::*'):
     tree.xpath('//body')[0].append(n)

tree.write(sys.argv[-1])
```

Save this to a file `merge.py` and run `chmod +x merge.py`.

```
Usage: merge.py [file1] ... [filen] [outfile]
```

If it fails, one or more files are malformed and need to be fixed either manually or with `htmllint` or `hxnormalize`.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way I found with out using any other programs is:
`cat html2.html >> html1.html`
This will add html2.html to the end of html1.html or if you want both of them in a new file you can type
`cat html1.html >> html3.html && cat html2.html >> html3.html`
Into the terminal. The >> appends the code in the file to the other code in the other one.

Comment: A simpler way to do this would be to go up a directory and then do something like `cat directory/*.html > merged_file.html` .  This is really really easy to do, but unfortunately it doesn't meet the question's requirements.