# How to join 1k files with less memory

Tags: unix, join, memory-management

Does any one know how to join 1k files using less memory ? Each file has 4 million rows and 10k columns.

I am using this script to  join 1k files at the moment. But it's failing even after specifying a memory size of 60 GB.

```
#!/bin/sh

# multijoin - join multiple files

join_rec() {
    if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
        join - "$1"
    else
        f=$1; shift
        join - "$f" | join_rec "$@"
    fi
}

if [ $# -le 2 ]; then
    join "$@"
else
    f1=$1; f2=$2; shift 2
    join "$f1" "$f2" | join_rec "$@"
fi
```

Source: [join multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726471/join-multiple-files)