# Join a specific column for several files and preserve file name as column name

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to merge some tab separated files:

File_A.tsv

```
probeId   BetaVal    Annot
  a         1         X
  b         2         Y
  c         3         Z
```

File_B.tsv

```
probeId   BetaVal    Annot
  a         4         X
  b         5         Y
  c         6         Z
```

File_C.tsv

```
probeId   BetaVal    Annot
  a         7         X
  b         8         Y
  c         9         Z
```

How can I merge these files by BetaVal column and stablish file name as column names (obtaining also a tab separated file)?

```
probeId  File_A.tsv   File_B.tsv   File_C.tsv   Annot
  a           1           4             7         X
  b           2           5             8         Y
  c           3           6             9         Z
```

I was trying something like:

```
for file in *;
do
join -j 1 File_A file;
done
```

But this is not correct. Moreover, I am not sure about how to write file names as column names.

Comment: Hi Jeni, may you please state how you determine that the columns headers should be A, B and C? But I don't `join` will do that for you...

Comment: Are there leading spaces or tabs and trailing newlines in your files as shown?

Comment: I am not sure about how to determine the headers. Actually, the header can be exactly the file name (I've edited the question)

Comment: What if number of rows are not same in all CSV files?

Comment: Which last column are you keeping?  Or, are you assuming the last column is identical in all flles?

Comment: I am assuming the last column is identical in all files. Moreover, the number of rows should be identical also in all files.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `gnu awk`:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{
   a[$1][ARGIND] = (FNR==1?FILENAME:$2)
   b[$1] = $3
}
END {
   for (i in a) {
      printf "%s", i
      for(j in a[i])
         printf "%s%s", OFS, a[i][j]
      print OFS b[i]
   }
}' File_[ABC].tsv | column -t
```

```
probeId  File_A.tsv  File_B.tsv  File_C.tsv  Annot
a        1           4           7           X
b        2           5           8           Y
c        3           6           9           Z
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo -e "\nprobeId  File_A.tsv   File_B.tsv   File_C.tsv   Annot";\
join -o 1.1 1.2 2.2 2.3 -1 1 -2 1 File_A.tsv File_B.tsv|\
join -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 2.2 1.4 -1 1 -2 1 - File_C.tsv |\
awk '{printf(" %-8s %-12s %-12s %-12s %s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5);}'|tail +2

probeId  File_A.tsv   File_B.tsv   File_C.tsv   Annot
 a        1            4            7            X
 b        2            5            8            Y
 c        3            6            9            Z
```

I assumed that the first column is the key field and I tried to guess 
what you thought but it would be better you read these links
to get more understanding about `join`:

https://linuxconfig.org/learning-linux-commands-join

https://landoflinux.com/linux_join_command.html

[join multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726471/join-multiple-files)