# Get common elements in 3 arrays in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

this code work for 2 arrays, but i want add one more array to compare, how do this?
Thanks

```
array1=(20 30 40 50)
array2=(10 20 30 80 100 110 40)
declare -a array3

#sort both arrays
readarray array1 <<<"$(printf "%s\n" "${array1[@]}" | sort -n)"
readarray array2 <<<"$(printf "%s\n" "${array2[@]}" | sort -n)"

# look for values
i2=0
for i1 in ${!array1[@]}; do
while (( i2 < ${#array2[@]} && ${array1[$i1]} > ${array2[$i2]} )); do (( i2++ )); done
[[ ${array1[$i1]} == ${array2[$i2]} ]] && array3+=(${array1[$i1]})
done


echo ${array3[@]}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [join multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726471/join-multiple-files); alternatively: `join <(join <(sort f1) <(sort f2)) <(sort f3)`; feeding results into a target array should be easy enough

Comment: Note that the current code is going to behave badly if your arrays contain literal newlines; using `readarray -d '' array1 < <(printf '%s\0' "${array1[@]}" | sort -nz)` would avoid that. (Granted, doesn't really matter if it's all numbers).

Comment: ...and _in general_, when you want to do set arithmetic (finding values that are common between two sorted streams -- or in only one or the other), the right tool for the job is `comm` instead of trying to roll your own. See [BashFAQ #36](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036).

Comment: (There are some quoting issues here, too, that stick out like a sore thumb; you lose all the advantages of `"${array[@]}"` over `${array[*]}` when you don't quote the expansion)

Comment: ...to get common items between three sorted streams in comm, you can just combine two instances: `comm -12 <(printf '%s\n' "${sortedListOne[@]}") <(comm -12 <(printf '%s\n' "${sortedListTwo[@]}") <(printf '%s\n' "${sortedListThree[@]}") )` -- do note that comm expects a lexicographic sort, not a numeric sort.

Answer (score 2):

Your fixed script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -ai array1=(20 30 40 50)
declare -ai array2=(10 20 30 80 100 110 40)
declare -ai array3=()

#sort both arrays
readarray -t array1 < <(printf "%s\n" "${array1[@]}" | sort -n)
readarray -t array2 < <(printf "%s\n" "${array2[@]}" | sort -n)

# look for values
i2=0
for i1 in "${!array1[@]}"; do
  while ((i2 < ${#array2[@]} && array1[i1] > array2[i2])); do
    ((i2++))
  done
  if [[ ${array1[$i1]} -eq ${array2[$i2]} ]]; then
    array3+=($((array1[i1])))
  fi
done

echo "${array3[@]}"
```

Or a shorter, more efficient, more reliable version working with any number of arrays

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -ai array1=(20 30 40 50)
declare -ai array2=(10 20 30 80 100 110 40)
declare -ai array3=(30 50 80 40 10)
declare -ai array4=(110 80 30 50 40)
declare -i arrays_cnt=4
declare -ai common=()

# Or in one go
mapfile -d '' common < <(
  printf %d\\0 "${array1[@]}" "${array2[@]}" "${array3[@]}" "${array4[@]}" \
    | sort -zn \
    | uniq -zcd \
    | grep -z "^\ *$arrays_cnt" \
    | cut -zb9-
)

echo "${common[@]}"
```

And if one really want not do it with external tools but with Bash 4.2+ associative arrays:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -ai array1=(20 30 40 50)
declare -ai array2=(10 20 30 80 100 110 40)
declare -ai array3=(30 50 80 40 10)
declare -ai array4=(110 80 30 50 40)
declare -i arrays_cnt=4
declare -ai common=()
declare -Ai key_count=()

# Count occurrences of keys
for k in "${array1[@]}" "${array2[@]}" "${array3[@]}" "${array4[@]}"; do
  key_count[$k]+=1
done

# Populates common array with non-unique keys
for k in "${!key_count[@]}"; do
  [ ${key_count[$k]} -eq $arrays_cnt ] && common+=("$k")
done

echo "${common[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks Léa, and if i add one more array?

Comment: @user14216283 more arrays is exactly the same and easy. Just add the additional arrays to the `print %d\\0`

Comment: i add a new array, but the result not is the only common values in 3 arrays, the result is the values that appers more than one time.

Comment: @user14216283 added support for any number of arrays