# bash/awk: remove duplicate columns after merging of several files

Tags: bash, awk, multiple-columns

I am using the following function written in my bash script in order to merge many files (contained multi-column data) into one big summary chart with all fused data

```
table_fuse () {   
    paste -d'\t' "${rescore}"/*.csv >> "${rescore}"/results_2PROTS_CNE_strategy3.csv | column -t -s$'\t'
}
```

Taking two files as an example, this routine would produce the following concatenated chart as the result of the merging:

```
# file 1.                   # file 2
Lig dG(10V1) dG(rmsd)   Lig dG(10V2) dG(rmsd)
lig1 -6.78 0.32 lig1 -7.04 0.20
lig2 -5.56 0.14 lig2 -5.79 0.45
lig3 -7.30 0.78 lig3 -7.28 0.71
lig4 -7.98 0.44 lig4 -7.87 0.42
lig5 -6.78 0.28 lig5 -6.75 0.31
lig6 -6.24 0.24 lig6 -6.24 0.24
lig7 -7.44 0.40 lig7 -7.42 0.39
lig8 -4.62 0.41 lig8 -5.19 0.11
lig9 -7.26 0.16 lig9 -7.30 0.13
```

Since the both files share the same first column (Lig), how would it be possible to remove (substitute to " ") all repeats of this column in each of the fussed file, while keeping only the Lig column from the first CSV?

Comment: You're saying you have code that adds the Lig column from all subsequent files while merging them and asking how to then remove it. Consider just not adding it in the first place. Your function won't work by the way - you're redirecting output of a command to a file and then trying to pipe the result of that redirection to `column`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As per OP's comments to cover `[Ll]ig` or `[Ll]ig0123` or `[Ll]ig(abcd)` formats in file adding following solution here.

```
awk '{first=$1;gsub(/[Ll]ig([0-9]+)?(\([-azA-Z]+\))?/,"");print first,$0}'  Input_file
```

---

---

With `awk` you could try following, considering that you want to remove only `lig(digits)` duplicate values here.

```
awk '{first=$1;gsub(/[Ll]ig([0-9]+)?/,"");print first,$0}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                   ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  first=$1              ##Setting first column value to first here.
  gsub(/[Ll]ig([0-9]+)?/,"")  ##Globally substituting L/lig digits(optional) with NULL in whole line.
  print first,$0        ##printing first and current line here.
}
' Input_file            ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: thank you! actually it does the job but skipping the name of the header as well (LIG). Could it be removed as well? What I noticed also that it add one column extra (LIG) at the begining of the file, so the resulted merged file contained 2 LIGS columns at the (in cells A and B) one with data (its OK!) and another empty..

Comment: @HotJAMS, Ok I have edited my code to handle lig OR Lig, also made digits after Lig/lig optional so that it takes care of header values also now, please do check it and let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thank you! In fact I need to remove completely the header of th first column which is Lig(CNE), so the present version left it as (CNE), I guess this RE in AWK should be further alitle bit modified to match this pattern :-)

Comment: @HotJAMS, ok sure, please try this one once `awk '{first=$1;gsub(/[Ll]ig([0-9]+)?(\([-azA-Z]+\))?/,"");print first,$0}'  Input_file` and let me know how it goes?

Comment: OK, thank you again! just one question - (as a potential bug) may this AWK sollution change the orders of the LINES while removing unused columns ??

Comment: @HotJAMS, order of lines will not be changed(considering you are running it on final merged file only), please do let me know if I could edit my answer with this `awk '{first=$1;gsub(/[Ll]ig([0-9]+)?(\([-azA-Z]+\))?/,"");print first,$0}'  Input_file` once? So that future readers get benefited from it too, let me know cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard to replace repeats of phrases. What exactly works for your case depends on the precise input file format; but something like

```sh
sed s/^\([^ ]*\)\( .* \)\1 /\1\2 /' file
```

would get rid of any repeat of the token in the first column.

Perhaps a better solution is to use a more sophisticated merge tool, though. A simple Awk or Python script could take care of removing the first token from every file except the first while merging.

Comment: Right, thank you! And yes, actually this was the only way how to merge data that I could find and adapt for my data. I will be thankful for any further ideas...

Comment: A simple Awk script to read one line from each of a set of open file handles and merge them will be easy to write, but not particularly robust for large numbers of input files. The typical limit is somewhere around 25 files. It should not be hard to find examples.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98945/a-better-paste-command has a solution with no limits on the number of files, but the drawback that the files need to fit into memory.

Answer (score 1):

`join` would appear to be a solution, at least for the sample data provided by OP ...

Sample input data:

```
$ cat file1
Lig dG(10V1) dG(rmsd)
lig1 -6.78 0.32
lig2 -5.56 0.14
lig3 -7.30 0.78
lig4 -7.98 0.44
lig5 -6.78 0.28
lig6 -6.24 0.24
lig7 -7.44 0.40
lig8 -4.62 0.41
lig9 -7.26 0.16

$ cat file2
Lig dG(10V2) dG(rmsd)
lig1 -7.04 0.20
lig2 -5.79 0.45
lig3 -7.28 0.71
lig4 -7.87 0.42
lig5 -6.75 0.31
lig6 -6.24 0.24
lig7 -7.42 0.39
lig8 -5.19 0.11
lig9 -7.30 0.13
```

We can `join` these two files on the first column (aka field) like such:

```
$  join -j1 file1 file2
Lig dG(10V1) dG(rmsd) dG(10V2) dG(rmsd)
lig1 -6.78 0.32 -7.04 0.20
lig2 -5.56 0.14 -5.79 0.45
lig3 -7.30 0.78 -7.28 0.71
lig4 -7.98 0.44 -7.87 0.42
lig5 -6.78 0.28 -6.75 0.31
lig6 -6.24 0.24 -6.24 0.24
lig7 -7.44 0.40 -7.42 0.39
lig8 -4.62 0.41 -5.19 0.11
lig9 -7.26 0.16 -7.30 0.13
```

For more than 2 files some sort of repetitive/looping method would be needed to repeatedly join a new file into the mix.

Comment: I've jsut tried like this: join -j1 "${directory_with_all_csvs}"/*.csv  > merged.csv.  and it did not work :-)

Comment: See the last sentence in the answer; `join` works on 2 files at a time; a google search on `linux join more than 2 files` will bring up multiple hits, eg, [join more than 2 files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10726471/7366100)

Comment: I gotcha it works normally to merge only two filles. Thank you!